# Hls.js works with a static script tag, but not dynamic

Tags: javascript, dynamic, hls.js

I'm trying to dynamically load the Hls.js library in a (typescript) webpage.
When I use a static `<script>` tag inside `<head>`, it works without a problem, but when I try to load Hls at runtime it fails with the message *Hls is not defined*

So this works:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js"></script>
<script>
console.log(Hls.isSupported());
</script>
```

But this doesn't (jQuery):

```
$.getScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js", (script, status, xhr) => { 
    console.log(Hls.isSupported());
});
```

And neither does a more traditional approach:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js");
script.onload = () => {
    console.log(Hls.isSupported());
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

In both cases, I can see the script being downloaded and showing up in the browser's Debugger pane (F12), but Hls is not defined.